# Lua same functions in different files

Tags: lua

I am making a with with an Entity Component System.  Each entity can have a script component with a lua script that controls behaviour.  Each file will look like this

```
function OnCreate()

end

function OnUpdate(timestep)

end
```

The problem is that the functions will be the latest that were loaded so it will be the latest `OnCreate` and latest `OnUpdate` functions.

How can I keep them separate so that I can call each entity's individual functions from c++?

Comment: Make the methods `entity:OnCreate()` and `entity:OnUpdate(timestep)` of an `entity` table per entity?

Comment: Use `local` and return the functions in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.  I have implemented it like this:

```
Person = {
    speed = 1,
    direction = {0.1, 0, 0}
}

function Person:OnCreate ()
   print(self.direction[1])
end

function Person:OnUpdate (timestep)
   print(self.speed + timestep)
end

RegisterEntity("Person")
```

In the cpp file:

```
struct ScriptManagerState
{
    lua_State* L;
    std::vector<std::string> m_ScriptObjects;
};
static ScriptManagerState scriptManagerState;

class ScriptManager
{
public:
    static void Initialise()
    {
        scriptManagerState.L = luaL_newstate();
        luaL_openlibs(scriptManagerState.L);
        lua_register(scriptManagerState.L, "RegisterEntity", lua_RegisterEntity);
    }

    static void LoadFile(std::string filename)
    {
        CheckLua(scriptManagerState.L, luaL_dofile(scriptManagerState.L, filename.c_str()));
    }

    static int lua_RegisterEntity(lua_State* L)
    {
        if (lua_isstring(scriptManagerState.L, -1) == true)
        {
            scriptManagerState.m_ScriptObjects.push_back(lua_tostring(scriptManagerState.L, -1));
            lua_pop(scriptManagerState.L, 2);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    
    static void OnCreate()
    {
        for (std::string entity : scriptManagerState.m_ScriptObjects)
        {
            lua_getglobal(scriptManagerState.L, entity.c_str());
            lua_getfield(scriptManagerState.L, -1, "OnCreate");
            lua_pushvalue(scriptManagerState.L, -2);
            CheckLua(scriptManagerState.L, lua_pcall(scriptManagerState.L, 1, 0, 0));
            lua_pop(scriptManagerState.L, 1);
        }
    }

    static void OnUpdate(float timestep)
    {
        for (std::string entity : scriptManagerState.m_ScriptObjects)
        {
            lua_getglobal(scriptManagerState.L, entity.c_str());
            lua_getfield(scriptManagerState.L, -1, "OnUpdate");
            lua_pushvalue(scriptManagerState.L, -2);
            lua_pushnumber(scriptManagerState.L, timestep);
            CheckLua(scriptManagerState.L, lua_pcall(scriptManagerState.L, 2, 0, 0));
            lua_pop(scriptManagerState.L, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

This I use it like this

```
    ScriptManager::Initialise();
    ScriptManager::LoadFile("test2.lua");
    ScriptManager::OnCreate();
    ScriptManager::OnUpdate(1/60.0f);
```